# Android text alignment inside textview is wrong

Tags: android, xml, textview

I'm trying to align text inside textview to the center (both vertical and horizontal).
Altought the vertical alignment working properlly in the Android Studio preview, it fails on the emulator.

The design:

[image]

The android studio preview:

[image]

The emulator:

[image]

The code:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/teamsBox"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="185dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="154dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/team_bg"
        android:padding="6dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/teamOneName"
            android:layout_width="143dp"
            android:layout_height="42dp"
            android:text="HOME"
            android:textColor="@color/my_white"
            android:background="@color/my_transparent"
            android:textSize="23sp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:gravity="center"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/teamOneScore"
            android:layout_width="143dp"
            android:layout_height="132dp"
            android:text="3"
            android:textColor="@color/my_green"
            android:textSize="127sp"
            android:gravity="center"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="154dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/team_bg"
        android:padding="6dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/teamTwoName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="42dp"
            android:text="AWAY"
            android:textColor="@color/my_white"
            android:background="@color/my_transparent"
            android:textSize="23sp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:gravity="center"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/teamTwoScore"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="132dp"
            android:text="1"
            android:textColor="@color/my_green"
            android:textSize="127sp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Edit:** I've changed to layout according to the answers, but the bug is still happening.
This is my new layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/teamsBox"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="185dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="154dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="@drawable/team_bg"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="6dp" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/teamOneName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="HOME"
            android:textColor="@color/my_white"
            android:background="@color/my_transparent"
            android:textSize="23sp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:gravity="center"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/teamOneScore"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="3"
            android:textColor="@color/my_green"
            android:textSize="127sp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="154dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/team_bg"
        android:padding="6dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/teamTwoName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="AWAY"
            android:textColor="@color/my_white"
            android:background="@color/my_transparent"
            android:textSize="23sp"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:gravity="center"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/teamTwoScore"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="1"
            android:textColor="@color/my_green"
            android:textSize="127sp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_gravity="center"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: set padding to textview

Comment: set margin_top="2dp" to textview

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To problem is in the TextView itself, the large size of the text is not calculated by the gravity attribute.

Try adding this attribute to your text view android:includeFontPadding="false"

Comment: Working like a charm! Thanks dear.

Answer (score 0):

set your textView's `android:gravity` to `center_vertical | center_horizontal`

```
<TextView
     android:id="@+id/teamOneScore"
     android:layout_width="143dp"
     android:layout_height="132dp"
     android:text="3"
     android:textColor="@color/my_green"
     android:textSize="127sp"
     android:gravity="center_vertical | center_horizontal" />
```

Comment: Didn't solve the problem.. I put the updated layout in the question body, you can look at it

Answer (score 0):

Remove hard coded `width` and `height` and use `weight`.Try the following data

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/teamsBox"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="185dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="154dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="@drawable/button_background"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="6dp" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/teamOneName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#123456"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="HOME"
            android:textSize="23sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/teamOneScore"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:text="3"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="127sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="154dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@drawable/button_background"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="6dp" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/teamTwoName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="#123456"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="AWAY"
            android:textSize="23sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/teamTwoScore"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
            android:text="1"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="127sp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Hope this works

Answer (score 0):

try this it may help you,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="154dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="6dp" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/teamOneName"
            android:layout_width="143dp"
            android:layout_height="42dp"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="HOME"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="23sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/teamOneScore"
            android:layout_width="143dp"
            android:layout_height="132dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="3"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="127sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="154dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="6dp" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/teamTwoName"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="42dp"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="AWAY"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="23sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/teamTwoScore"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="132dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="1"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="127sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Didn't solve the problem.. I put the updated layout in the question body, you can look at it

Answer (score 0):

Your linear layout which is having the edit text and one text view height is lesser than you have given height to its children. Please calculate height for the edit text and text view and accordingly adjust height of your linear layout.

Here You just need to give wrap_content to you text view and .

```
1. change in text view 

    android:layout_height="132dp"

To

    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

2. Increase you linear layout height to

    android:layout_width="184dp"

3. remove below pading tag from your linear layout

    android:padding="6dp"
```

it will fix your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Just use match_parent as the height of the textview.